# GeoServer time data cannot add store

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html) but I can't create `store`. I get error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:data/sgistime and hints Hints:
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1a6164c[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@1dd60979                                                                                  
System defaults:
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                  
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                   
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                  
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                     
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@ea9e141
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                  
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                      
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                  

    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1574)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1517)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:128)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:99)
    ... 154 more
```

My guess is it is maybe something related to:

```
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
```

based on `Unknown source` feedback.

Here is gdalinfo of input TIFF file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\Users\user\geoserver\data_dir\data\sgistime\gfs50kmTemperature20130310T180000000Z_0200.000_.tiff
Size is 151, 91
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-30.000000000000000,70.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.496688741721854,-0.494505494505495)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -30.0000000,  70.0000000) ( 30d 0' 0.00"W, 70d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -30.0000000,  25.0000000) ( 30d 0' 0.00"W, 25d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right (  45.0000000,  70.0000000) ( 45d 0' 0.00"E, 70d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (  45.0000000,  25.0000000) ( 45d 0' 0.00"E, 25d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      (   7.5000000,  47.5000000) (  7d30' 0.00"E, 47d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

GeoServer plugin adds table with layer name to postgis database, here is table screenshot:
[image]

How can I resolve this?

indexer.properties

```
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
```

timeregex.properties

```
regex=.*([0-9]{10}).*,format=yyyyMMddHH
```

Comment: please add the contents of your index files

Comment: OK. I figured it out eventually. I am using non standard time format, so I have to specify it in timeregex.properties. I did that with adding format=yyyyMMddHH at end of file.